# Index strategy for a Queue Table, getting rid of filesort

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, query, sorting

I am trying to get rid of a filesort operation (and preferably also optimize a bottleneck query). We are using an innodb mysql table as a queue to process various incoming business activities. It is not uncommon for the queue to have several hundred thousand pending items to process.

The selection query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    id,
    user,
    password,
    counter,
    idoc,
    idoc_type,
    company_id,
    host,
    job_id
FROM
    business_queue
WHERE
        finished IS NULL
    AND locked='0'
    AND created <= NOW()
    AND counter <= 5
    AND company_id = 2
ORDER BY
    business_object_priority DESC, created ASC, id ASC
LIMIT 1
FOR UPDATE
```

The table has the follwing index defined:

```
ALTER TABLE  `business_queue` ADD INDEX compound_selector(
   `finished` ,  
   `locked`,    
   `created`,    
   `counter`,    
   `company_id`,   
   `business_object_priority` ) ;
```

Yet I have a feeling that it could be massively optimized, as currently filesort is used for sorting and it is kinda inefficient when we have a large pending queue. Is there a way to get rid of filesort in the above query completey?

Comment: What about defining an index on your columns used in ordering?

Comment: Yeah, I have these too, but afaik mysql uses only one index anyway.

Comment: And adding `id` to `compound_selector`?

Comment: Sorry, ID is the primary key. According to MySQL Docs the primary key is always automatically added as the very first part of any compound index.

Comment: Could you give a link to that?

Comment: @dezso: I suppose clops is referring to InnoDB, where the clustered key (usually the PK, but not always) is added (as the last part AFAIK) to all non-clustered indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look at the WHERE clause

```
WHERE
        finished IS NULL
    AND locked='0'
    AND created <= NOW()
    AND counter <= 5
    AND company_id = 2
ORDER BY
    business_object_priority DESC, created ASC, id ASC
```

Since `company_id` and `locked` are static values, they should be the leading columns of the index. Your ORDER BY has `business_object_priority DESC` and `created ASC`. Because of this mixed order, there will always be a filesort to contend with.

Notwithstanding, I would rearrange the column order as follows

```
ALTER TABLE  `business_queue` ADD INDEX compound_selector_new (
    `company_id`,   
    `locked`,    
    `finished`
    `business_object_priority`) ;
```

Notice the following:

- I removed `created` and `counter` because you have ranges specified in the `WHERE` clause.
- I kept `finished` because you need all records with `company_id=2` and `locked=0` grouped with all finished columns that are NULL.

Although there will be a filesort, this should yield a faster collection of rows.

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: Thanks, its awesome! What is the recommended way then to sort a queue to keep up with the following prerequisite: higher priority business objects should be handled first, then order by created date. Filesort is non-avoidable or?